# Problems setting up git with github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3, github

I've googled the heck out of this one, and it is still failing me.

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Most of the problems with this seem to do with having the wrong keys being sent to the server,
which isn't the problem. I can SSH into github as stated in github's help pages. I did have this working fine before, but I had wiped out the repository, wiped out my keys, and started fresh.
Here is the output of `ssh -v git@github.com`:

> OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
>   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   debug1: Applying options for *
>   debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
>   debug1: Connection established.
>   debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
>   debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
>   debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
>   debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: identity file /home/patrick/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2
>   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5github2 pat OpenSSH*
>   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>   debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
>   debug1: Found key in /home/patrick/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
>   debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
>   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
>   debug1: Offering public key: /home/patrick/.ssh/id_rsa
>   debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve blueshift9
>   debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
>   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
>   debug1: Remote: Forced command: gerve blueshift9
>   debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
>   debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
>   debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
>   debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
>   debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
>   debug1: Entering interactive session.
>   debug1: Sending environment.
>   debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.utf8
>   PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
>   Hi! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
>             debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
>   Connection to github.com closed.
>   Transferred: sent 2648, received 2904 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
>   Bytes per second: sent 37663.4, received 41304.6
>   debug1: Exit status 1

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844393/what-to-do-about-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0

Comment: Thanks ghoppe; I had actually tried that at some point, didn't work, tried again, worked! Thanks! If you add it as an answer, I can checkmark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

what exactly are you doing to get this error? it suggests you're trying to connect to git@github, not git@github.com

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

---

this means there is nothing wrong with your keys:

> debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
>
> ...
>
> Hi! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: I am trying to do a `git push origin master`. According to the docs, when setting where I want my origin to be, it needs to be github.com, so I am confused as to why it is saying just github.