# How to gain shell access when I'm locked out with "PTY allocation request failed on channel 0"

Tags: git, ssh, gitosis, tty, pty

I installed gitosis on a remote shell. It's working fine. But now I can't login to the interactive shell. As told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844393/what-to-do-about-pty-allocation-request-failed-on-channel-0), it seem gitosis disabled tty. Is there anyway I can get it back? I don't have root access to the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to login if you make your ssh client not ask for a tty, probably by using the `-T` flag.

e.g.

```
ssh -T remotehost
```

You will not get a shell prompt, the normal editing keys will not work, and you won't be able to use full screen programs such as vi, emacs or less, but you will be able to run simple shell commands.

I don't know how to re-enable the tty though, sorry.

Comment: No, that gives me 
    ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Need SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in environment.